# having trouble trying to keep users logged in with addStateDidChangeListener()

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, listener, appdelegate

So my goal for now is to successfully keep users logged in and show a certain viewController depending if they're logged in or not. I've read a lot of the Stack questions that showed up first on Google searches about this same topic and they said use `addStateDidChangeListener()` and that's exactly what I did.

I didn't know how to approach this, so I watched a Youtube video and copied the exact code the guy had, his project did what I wanted mine to do, so I gave it a shot. Unfortunately when I run the simulator, sign in, exit the simulator and simulate again, nothing changes. I will add my code and it's location.

This is the code in my `AppDelegate.swift` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
     let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    
    auth.addStateDidChangeListener { (_, user) in
        switch user {
        case nil:
            guard self.activeViewController! is StudentSegmentedTableViewController else { return }
            let nonLoggedInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.GothereMainMenuStoryboardID) as! GothereMainMenuViewController
            self.navigationController.setViewControllers([nonLoggedInViewController], animated: false)
            self.navigationController.popToViewController(nonLoggedInViewController, animated: true)
            self.activeViewController = nonLoggedInViewController
            
        default:
            guard self.activeViewController! is GothereMainMenuViewController else { return }
            let alreadyLoggedInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.StudentEventDashboardStoryboardID) as! StudentSegmentedTableViewController
            self.navigationController.setViewControllers([alreadyLoggedInViewController], animated: false)
            self.navigationController.popToViewController(alreadyLoggedInViewController, animated: true)
            self.activeViewController = alreadyLoggedInViewController
        }
    }
    
    let nonLoggedInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.GothereMainMenuStoryboardID) as! GothereMainMenuViewController
    let alreadyLoggedInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.StudentEventDashboardStoryboardID) as! StudentSegmentedTableViewController
    
    activeViewController = nonLoggedInViewController
    
    switch Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    case true:
        activeViewController = alreadyLoggedInViewController
    default:
        break
    }
    
    navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: activeViewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I tried just this alone at first, and it didn't work so then I implemented a state listener in reasonable spots in my app.

First I added one that enables right after successful log in/signup and the segue is performed .

```
func enableAuth() {
   authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (_, user) in
        print("State Listener activated")
    }
}
```

This is what I call in the `viewDidLoad()` of the segued viewController right after login/signup. To remove it, I simply call it when the logout button is pressed..

```
func disableAuthState() {
    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(self.authListener!)
    print("State Listener Deactivated")

}

func studentLogoutSelected() {
    var text = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .default) { (logoutAction) in
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            self.disableAuthState()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.studentLogout, sender: self)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("There was an error signing the user out. \(signOutError)")
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(logoutAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

After all these functions and implementations, the shown blocks of code still don't do what I expected them to do. If anybody can point out issues or suggestions, that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you add FirebaseApp.configure() on your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in appdelegate? Then, Can you try call enableAuth in viewWillAppear()

Comment: Yes my `FirebaseApp.configure() ` is right above the first block of code I added inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  I will try to call `enableAuth()` in `viewWillAppear()` instead. @Alperen Polat Gezgin

Comment: It still doesn't change the result. @Alperen Polat Gezgin

Comment: Did you call Auth.signInwith..() method in anywhere?

Comment: Yes I call it in the LoginViewController right when the login button is clicked, I also tried putting the enableAuth() in that closure as well but I get the same result. I think it would make the most sense to have it in the viewController presented right after login/signup, would it not? @Alperen Polat Gezgin

Comment: You should call enableAuth() func in SignIn ViewController on viewWillAppear(). Because when on start Auth is nil and when user logined Auth is changed and trigger stateListener.